# npm/gulp grabbing lots of modules that are not defined in the package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I really am struggling to understand why in every video tutorial I follow exactly where I simply run the "npm install" or even "gulp install"  it downloads a lot of modules (at least 150 separate node modules that aren't even defined in my package.json file) that I have no clue what they are or what they do but I've attempted to research the issue with not a whole lot of success!

Comment: I have 136 different folders in my node_modules after only using npm install gulp --sav-dev in a brand new directory... so weird

Comment: there are two comments on the answer below explaining this behavior.

Comment: So you're saying it's normal behavior for it to take 5 minutes just to simply install gulp and slap 200 random folders in my node_modules folder when in this video i'm watching it's near instant and he only has things like "gulp", "gulp-sass", "brower-sync" in his modules folder nice and neat.

Comment: you're probably not using the same version of npm. v2 used to put all the dependencies for a module in its own node_modules directory, while v3 puts them all together. check out this: https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3

Comment: Even upon following newbostons tutorials (created last month) down to a tee and he doesn't have nearly the same amount of random crap in his modules folder EDIT: Ohh just followed your link... So the new version literally must of JUST come out.. Weird update i'd say if it aims to make your modules folder all cluttered and unreadable :(

Comment: do you mean the "node.js for beginners" series? those are from first half of 2015, and probably using npm v2.

Comment: Im refering to his "Gulp (Gulp.js) Tutorial for Beginners" which was started right around march 10th last month

Comment: @Fullstackdream it's entirely possible he's using npm v2 still, rather than v3. v2 isn't nearly as neat as it might appear to be. It's just pushing all dependencies into the folders, (which caused some interesting issues with path length on Windows) but they're all still there. v3 adopted a flat file structure wherever possible, which makes the top level folder look a lot messier, but it's actually cleaner overall, since it attempts to use the same dependency between different packages that require it, providing the semver matches.

Comment: i've checked the videos, and he's definitely using npm v1/v2.

Comment: that's how npm v3 works, and i'm afraid you just have to deal with it. or use outdated software which i don't think anyone would recommend.

Comment: Thank you so much Brandon & Hatsuney for these answers it is what i've been looking for!!! Explains why a lot of things are / aren't happening in these video tutorials!

Comment: @Fullstackdream Not a problem :) Feel free to reach out to me directly through the email in my profile if you want/need some more detailed help/explanations.

Comment: Wow thanks for the amazing resource i'm working hard to understand how this all works :D

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing are module dependencies being installed. You may only depend on/install a few modules, but those modules may have their own set of dependencies and each of those dependencies may their own dependencies, and so on.

Comment: Upon inspecting the node_modules folder (in multiple video tutorials i'm watching) it appears that there is nothing but only a couple folders in their node_modules folder but no matter how simple my package.json folder is it still installs hundreds of dependencies that weren't present in any video tutorial  (I'm certain this isn't intentional)

Comment: can you provide an example list of dependencies you have in your package.json?

Comment: For example if I am trying to setup a new project with only sass and live reload, I would simply install them and save to the pacakge.json.. when I go to npm install / gulp install it install it takes like 8 minutes to install the hundreds of other dependencies (which I'm sure it doesn't need?)

Comment: gulp has 13 dependencies. live-reload has 7. those dependencies usually have their own dependencies too, and that's why you need to install so many.

Comment: @Fullstackdream You can run `npm ls`, and that will show you the full dependency tree. You can also check out what a package depends on using npm's site or `npm info <package name>`. But yeah, one dependency can easily balloon in to many more, depending on how many it requires in its `package.json`. For example, `gulp` has 13 dependencies, and each of those may have their own dependencies as well.

Comment: @Fullstackdream, you seem to have neglected the link, but to put it simply, how many packages you end up installing simply depends on the packages. One package may not have any dependencies, but another may have dozens, with each of those dependencies with dependencies of their own, and so on. https://asciinema.org/a/1b0cd3ya3rzw5h7moafdanvhi